# what's the point in assembling imperial resources after the update?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

After the update, imperial resources cost credits to create but the reward is far less than the amount it will cost to assemble all the resources. For example, one assignment would require over 1,700,000 credits but the reward is only 30,000. So what is the point in assembling resources if you're just losing all your money?

Comment: TBH, the devs just want you to buy more bux.

Comment: That's very cynical since I've never bought bux in either of these two games and they give them out like 2 cent candy.

Comment: Except that there's no way to spend Bux to increase net profit from imperial assignments. An unprofitable assignment is worthless no matter how many Bux you spend, so there's no incentive to spend them.

Comment: They rebalanced the rewards once... they will likely do it again. There's no reason to have a part of the game that's pointless...

Answer (score 1):

Completing Imperial Resources to complete the Imperial tasks does earn you Bux, Coins, and the occasional VIP.

I make them constantly on all floors so that, hopefully, when I complete one task, the next one can be completed immediately with stock on hand.

When initially released, the rewards for tasks was less than the cost to build the items total but it has since been rebalanced making it worthwhile to complete the tasks... with the cost update recently, it's out of whack again but, hopefully, they will rebalance to make the reward better again.

Comment: You can also get costumes from these tasks

Comment: Oh really?  Is that new?  You can get them outside the event prizes?  That's cool.

Comment: It's not that cool  You don't get new costumes.  You get one more copy of an existing costume.  It's a very poor reward.

Comment: That is crummy since you get so many costumes for free when you cycle through the bitizens.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a little more content for people who have completed towers.  When you have 5 million coins, or 20 million lying around, why not spend them doing imperial missions?